# How does 恋バナ function here?

Tags: translation

Been reading more japanese material lately and ran into this dialogue.

Person 1:ホント毎週転がり込んで...

Person 2:まーたそんな水臭いこと！そんな気遣うヒマあったら恋バナの一つでも持って来いっての！

For context 2 people are drinking beer at home. Person 1 is the nephew of person 2.

I can pretty much understand "まーたそんな水臭いこと！" and "ホント毎週転がり込んで". The final line is what stumps me. As a far I know, "そんな気遣うヒマあったら" translates to "if you have the time to worry about that, then..."

Does the "恋バナの一つでも持って来いっての！" translate to "gossip with me?" or "share a love story or two" or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the nephew is trying to apologize for barging in on Person 2:s home so frequently. Person 2 is saying "You don't have to worry about that, silly. But if you really want to pay back, find yourself a girlfriend and let me hear all about it after you do" or something to that effect. As such, it seems likely that Person 2 is a 'nice person' who is basically telling Person 1 "All that matters to me is that you find happiness in your life" in a roundabout way.

It is possible that Person 2 is simply interested in gossip in general, though. Still, since Person 1 is their nephew, I would assume they are referring to their nephew's personal life and that the context is as I conjectured above.